# HD Wallets - Generating P2SH-P2WSH Addresses from a ypub-type mpks in PHP?

Tags: segregated-witness, php

I am writing a webapp in PHP that needs to generate Bitcoin addresses from their mpk.

I have successfully done it for P2SH addresses (starting with a 1, with a xpub mpk) using the [BitWasp php library](https://github.com/Bit-Wasp/bitcoin-php), roughly using the method outlined [here](https://freedomnode.com/blog/58/generate-bitcoin-wallet-addresses-from-extended-public-key-with-php).

I wanted to do the same for P2SH-P2WSH addresses (starting with a 3, with a ypub mpk) to make use of SegWit, but I always get the same error, using the same method (using the 49' derivation path instead of 44'):

HD key magic bytes do not match network magic bytes.

I have checked and this library can generate P2SH-P2WSH addresses, but so far, I have only been able to generate them from the raw public key (following Bitwasp's examples).

So I was wondering, could I be pointed towards a method to generate the P2SH-P2WSH addresses from their ypub using PHP only?